# How to make a more efficient mapping function based on a dataframe with the index and column name of another dataframe as its dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe with column ['Subtype'] and ['Building Condition'],

Dataframe 1:

| Subtype | Building Condition |
| --- | --- |
| A | Good |
| B | Bad |
| C | Bad |

I want to map dataframe 1 using another dataframe based on the values of those two columns

Dataframe 2:

|  | Good | Bad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Repair | Retrofit |
| B | Retrofit | Reconstruct |
| C | Reconstruct | Reconstruct |

Iterate over the first dataframe and use the [pd.df.at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) function for each row and append them to an empty list.

```
#assignment of intervention based on subtype and building condition
intervention_list = []
for index, row in bldg_df.iterrows():
    # print(bldg_df.at[index, 'Subtype'])
    intervention = matrix_df.at[bldg_df['Subtype'][index], 
                                bldg_df['Building Condition'][index]]
    intervention_list.append(intervention)   

bldg_df['Intervention'] = intervention_list
```

So the resulting dataframe would be

| Subtype | Building Condition | Intervention |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Good | Repair |
| B | Bad | Reconstruct |
| C | Bad | Reconstruct |

This worked but I'm just thinking if there's a faster and more efficient way of going about this. Maybe using the map or merge as_of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documented approach in such case is to use [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) on the underyling [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) array:

```
# factorize the requested name
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df1['Building Condition'])

# reorder and slice
df1['Intervention'] = (df2.reindex(index=df1['Subtype'], columns=cols)
                          .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df1)), idx]
                       )
```

Output:

```
  Subtype Building Condition Intervention
0       A               Good       Repair
1       B                Bad  Reconstruct
2       C                Bad  Reconstruct
```

This is also the most efficient approach:

[image]

Comment: Although a bit more complicated than the other solutions, I found this to be the fastest method which was almost 10x faster than what I did lol

Comment: @John there used to be a `lookup` function that was doing this seamlessly, but it's been deprecated

Answer (score 2):

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Subtype': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Building Condition': ['Good', 'Bad', 'Bad']}
data2 = {'Good': {'A': 'Repair', 'B': 'Retrofit', 'C': 'Reconstruct'}, 
         'Bad': {'A': 'Retrofit', 'B': 'Reconstruct', 'C': 'Reconstruct'}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

df1:

```
  Subtype Building Condition
0       A               Good
1       B                Bad
2       C                Bad
```

df2:

```
          Good          Bad
A       Repair     Retrofit
B     Retrofit  Reconstruct
C  Reconstruct  Reconstruct
```

---

**Code**

unpivot and merge

```
tmp = (df2.stack().reset_index()
       .set_axis(['Subtype', 'Building Condition', 'Intervention'], axis=1)
)
out = df1.merge(tmp, how='left')
```

out

```
  Subtype Building Condition Intervention
0       A               Good       Repair
1       B                Bad  Reconstruct
2       C                Bad  Reconstruct
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `itertuples`:

```
df1.assign(Intervention = df2.stack().loc[df1.itertuples(False)].values)

  Subtype Building Condition Intervention
0       A               Good       Repair
1       B                Bad  Reconstruct
2       C                Bad  Reconstruct
```

Answer (score 1):

I think simpliest is [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html):

```
out = (bldg_df.join(matrix_df.stack().rename('Intervention'),
                    on=['Subtype','Building Condition']))
print (out)
  Subtype Building Condition Intervention
0       A               Good       Repair
1       B                Bad  Reconstruct
2       C                Bad  Reconstruct
```

Alternative with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
out = (bldg_df.join(matrix_df.melt(ignore_index=False, 
                                  value_name='Intervention')
                             .set_index('variable', append=True), 
                    on=['Subtype','Building Condition']))
print (out)
  Subtype Building Condition Intervention
0       A               Good       Repair
1       B                Bad  Reconstruct
2       C                Bad  Reconstruct
```

Or with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
bldg_df['Intervention'] = (bldg_df.set_index(['Subtype','Building Condition']).index
                                  .map(matrix_df.stack()))
print (bldg_df)
  Subtype Building Condition Intervention
0       A               Good       Repair
1       B                Bad  Reconstruct
2       C                Bad  Reconstruct
```

**Detail**:

```
print (matrix_df.stack().rename('Intervention'))
A  Good         Repair
   Bad        Retrofit
B  Good       Retrofit
   Bad     Reconstruct
C  Good    Reconstruct
   Bad     Reconstruct
Name: Intervention, dtype: object
```